# Display Current Location Path (with slashes) of any file in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch file to automatically find the location of a file called "file.txt".
I want the batch file to print exactly word to word, slash to slash, the path of a file present on my computer!! My MAIN idea is that the file's location must be able to be found by the batch file irrespective of wherever it is on my computer.

For eg, if the directory path of the file is " **C:\users\desktop\folder\file.txt** ", I want the batch file to automatically find this file, copy its path and send it exactly as it is to another text file called say "location.txt". I HOPE THE QUESTION IS CLEAR NOW!!

But the following I think is only for current directory path of the batch file and not any other file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "mypath=%cd%"
set "stringtoreplace=toto"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt') do (
set "content=%%a"
set "content=!content:%stringtoreplace%=%mypath%!"
echo !content!
))>output.txt
```

Comment: Does `test.txt` contain a file location? Is there a list of multiple locations?

Comment: This question is unclear. what does `test.txt` contain? what do you mean by display exact path if you show you specifically only access `file.txt`? what I can see is you access the file, and pipe the content of the file to another file, with the exeption of the replacement you do. I am assuming you want to do display the string path inside of the file `file.txt` but until I know for sure what you want, I cannot help.

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you guys, but yes I want to display the directory path of a file, for eg, C:\users\folder\file.txt, exactly as it is to another text file say location.txt.

Comment: but you are still being unclear. where must we find these files? do you have a list of files in the test.txt file? what files do you want the path to? show example content of you file, and show expected output, then I can help.

Comment: Do you want to search for `file.txt` and get its location?

Comment: Ok guys, so imagine there is a file called "file.txt" on my computer. I want a batch file that can automatically locate this file, and then somehow be able to copy its location path ( for eg. the "C:\user\...) and then send this exactly word to word and slash to slash to another text file called "location.txt". My main idea is that the batch file must be able to recognise the path irrespective of where the user puts his file.txt. I hope it's clear NOW!

Comment: What is clear is that the code you've provided in your question does not in any way perform anything like the task you've now explained. In fact it is clear that you've made no attempt to research the commands you'll need or use the search facility. This purpose of this site is to help you fix your own code which has been written for the task you've laid out, not for someone else to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand your edit correctly, you try to find a file (with unknown location) and get its actual location.

The following will look for the file(s) `file.txt` in `C:\users\` and it's subfolders amd write the list to `output.txt`:

```
dir /s /b "C:\users\file.txt" >output.txt
```

**Edit**

To find a file "wherever it is on the system", you have to search on each drive.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption /value') do (
  dir /s /b "%%a:\file.txt" >>output.txt
)
```

(`drivetype=3` would be all your hard drives. If you want to check thumb drives too,  add the same line a second time, but change `3` to `2` (and a third line with `5` if you have to check CD-drives too))

Comment: I was also thinking this, but somehow the fact that he used `type test.txt` and doing search and replace for `toto` makes me think he wants to access filenames within it, but let's see what OP comes back with. +1 anyway.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes, a look at the contents of `test.txt` (as requested several times in the comments) would help a lot to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a stab in the dark here because your question is unclear, but I am assuming you have a list of files in the file `test.txt` which for some strange reason contains the word `toto` in it. If that is the case, then this should be more or less what you want.

It will access the file, get each line and then search for `toto` and replace it with nothing, then do a search using `dir /s` with `findstr`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "stringtoreplace=toto"
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set "content=%%a"
    set "content=!content:%stringtoreplace%=!"
    for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s ^| findstr !content!') do echo %%i
)
)>>output.txt
```