# How to use a batch file on any computer in any directory

Tags: batch-file

I have the direcotry that contain O365 setup files as below

```
C:\O365\Office\Data\version\
```

I created a very basic batch file to execute the below command to setup O365.

```
@echo off
C:\O365\Office\Setup.exe /configure C:\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml
```

I can run the batch file if the O365 folder is locate to `C:\`

But if I want to copy the batch file and whole O365 folder to another PC and save it on desktop or on D drive. So how can I still to run the batch file without changing the directory inside the batch file?

The batch file is locating in the last sub folder of the directory `C:\O365\Office\Data\version\O365.bat`

I don't know what to change to replace the `C:\` in the batch file so that I can use it anywhere and no matter the O365 folder will save to Desktop or D or anywhere.

Can anyone help?

PS: I don't want to put the O365.bat in the same folder with the setup.exe.

I just want to put the O365.bat into the last subfolder.

**Edit1**: I edited the batch file with Stephan's advice.

Changed the command in batch file to

```
%~dp0..\..\Setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0..\..\Configure-O365PP.xml
```

And the batch file work. I can copy to any and execute the batch file.

Then, I converted that batch file to .exe file by using "iexpress".

After converted to the .exe file, the above command doesn't work anymore.
It cannot execute the command.

How to make it work after converting to .exe file?

**Edid 2**: With advice from @sst, I can convert the batch file to .EXE with below command

```
%~dp0..\..\Setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0..\..\Configure-O365PP.xml
```

And input `cmd /c O365.bat "#e"` to the install command in iexpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%~dp0` is the full path of your batch file.

```
C:\O365\Office\Data\version\
```

From here you can use relative paths:

```
"C:\O365\Office\Setup.exe" /configure "C:\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml"
```

would change to

```
      "%~dp0..\..\Setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0..\..\Configure-O365PP.xml"
```

where `..` is "one folder up"

Let's say you copy it to a users desktop, then the batch file's location `%~dp0` is

```
C:\Users\someone\desktop\O365\Office\Data\version\
```

Two up is

```
C:\Users\someone\desktop\O365\Office\
```

(that's were `setup.exe` and `XML` resides)

The line

```
"%~dp0..\..\Setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0..\..\Configure-O365PP.xml"
```

would then execute as

```
"C:\Users\someone\desktop\O365\Office\Setup.exe" /configure "C:\Users\someone\desktop\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml
```

Learn more about those `%~` modifiers by reading the output of `call /?`

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your quick response. I used "%~dp0..\..\Setup.exe" /configure "%~dp0..\..\..\Configure-O365PP.xml" on the batch file and it works. However, if I convert the batch file to exe file by using iexpress. Then the command does not work. Can you help more? How can I still use those command in while convert it to exe file?

Comment: My setup.exe and .XML file are locate in the same folder. They are C:\O365\Office\Setup.exe and C:\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml

Comment: When you convert your batch file into an `.EXE`, all the `.EXE` does, is unpacking the original batch file into a temporary file (probably in a temporary folder) and run it from there. Then, of course, original folder information isn't valid anymore. You'll have to [search your folder or file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54171800/2152082) instead, but that would take quite some time and is limited to a single drive (could take several minutes - depending on the type of your disk (HDD/SSD) and how much data it holds).

Comment: When I used the batch file with command "C:\O365\Office\Setup.exe /configure C:\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml" to convert to .EXE file. I can run that .EXE and execute the command without any issue. I doubt that "%~dp0" get issue when convert to .EXE therefore it cannot execute the command???

Comment: of course, it runs with the full absolute path. It's the relative paths that get confused because the batch file isn't anymore where it's supposed to be (but in a temporary folder, created by the .EXE wrapper). If you put an `echo My full name is `%~f0` at the beginning of your batch file, convert to `.exe` and run it to see, where it's located.

Comment: Perhaps the [system environment variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) may help also: `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%UserProfile%`, etc....

Comment: @aschipfl: unlikely, when users seem to copy it to some random location (even non-system drives). Lionking: two pieces of advice: 1) don't use Batch2Exe converters, 2) educate your users

Comment: @Liongkong, I'm not sure why you need to encapsulate your batch file in an IExpress package, but if you really need to, for whatever reason, there is a solution. Just specify the special Iexpress placeholder `"#e"` as the command line argument of your batch file. The `#e` Placeholder will be replaced by the full path to your Iexpress executable package. You will also need to replace all instances of `%~dp0` by `%~dp1` in your batch file. So for example if your batch file is named `osetup.cmd` then in the IExpress setup specify `cmd /c osetup.cmd "#e"` as the install command.

Comment: @sst, thanks alot. when change to %~dp1 and use /c osetup.cmd "#e" as the install command. It worked when converted to .EXE

Comment: @Stephan, the [%~dp0] work for the full path [C:\O365\Office\Data\version\]". But how aboult if I want to put the .bat file to [C:\O365\Office\]?. What should I change on the path? If [..] is one folder up. So, what will present for one folder down?

Comment: `"%~dp0version"` obviously.

Comment: @Stephan, It should be `"%~dp0Office"` instead, right? Because I put the batch file in ``C:\O365\Office\``

Comment: If you put the batch file into `C:\O365\Office`, then `%~dp0` is `C:\O365\Office\`. That's where also `Setup.exe` and `Configure-O365PP.xml` is. Why do you want to go "one down"?

Comment: @Stephan, I will put the batch file into ``C:\O365\Office\``, the batch file will inside Office folder. So, if i just use ``%~dp0`` it will be ``C:\O365\Setup.exe`` and ``C:\O365\Configure-O365PP.xml``. The correct directory should be ``C:\O365\Office\Setup.exe`` and ``C:\O365\Office\Configure-O365PP.xml``. So the command should be: ``%~dp0Office\Setup.exe /configure %~dp0Office\Configure-O365PP.xml``

Comment: If you put the batch file into `C:\O365\Office` then `%~dp0` is `C:\O365\Office\`. Simple as that.